# OpenLayers KML Remote Icon don't show on mobile device

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, openlayers

Hi I'm using OpenLayer for creating HTML5 Mobile Applicaton. I use Vector Layers that contain
KML with next part of code:

```
<IconStyle>
        <Icon>
            <href>//23.23.23.23/images/img.png</href>
            <href>//23.23.23.23/images/img.png</href>
            <scale>2.1</scale>
        </Icon>
        <hotSpot x="14" y="14" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
 </IconStyle>
```

All Works on my laptop, but when i test on my mobile phone instead of this image there is show  image with question mark....I've googled for this but I didn't found any solutions....The problem is only when is viewed on mobile device :(

- The URL in this example is not real, but in the original code this is ok and the image exist on the server....(as i say It's all right on my laptop and there is shown correctly).

Comment: I fixed this by adding http://23.23.23.23/images/img.png instead of //23.23.23.23/images/img.png